# IIS: Setting authorization/authentication on a folder

Tags: iis, authorization, directory, adfs

Sorry if this is too basic but I'm new to IIS and settings.

if possible, how can I set an authorization on folder in IIS?

I have a folder on a web server which is very often updated. This folder should be accessible on the web but for certain users only. What options are there to authenticate a user via a form and/or ADFS?

Right now, the folder is available to everyone, but I want to limit its access.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is iis7 you can limit the folder to certain users.

On the folder you would like to access, Right Click and go to the **Security** Tab. Click on **Advanced**, then click on **Change Permissions**, add/remove users to the list and make sure you UNCHECK **Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent**.

I image if you want public access that is limited you can authenticate your forms via windows authentication.

Comment: Thanks. I want to allow it to a particular domain and not a specific user. Can such permissions be set? About the form: where do I create the form and tie it to this folder? Any tutorial u know of will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible. Try this article which gives a fairly concise tutorial of windows authentication in ASP.NET [Windows Authentication in .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323176). I learned using a book from Apress called, "ASP.NET 4 in C# 2010". Chapter 19 (security fundamentals) covers this topic more in depth.

Answer (score 0):

ADFS protects AD - you can specify rules that restrict access to AD components e.g. OU.

For a folder, have a group (role) in AD, set up a claim rule and only allow access in your application if the user has that role.